# c++ Map order of objects

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm wondering why my output looks like this:

```
This : 1
a : 4
is : 2
just : 3
test : 5
```

When my code looks like this:

```
map<string, int> wordCount;
wordCount["This"] = 1;
wordCount["is"] = 2;
wordCount["just"] = 3;
wordCount["a"] = 4;
wordCount["test"] = 5;
for (map<string, int>::iterator it = wordCount.begin();
        it != wordCount.end(); it++)  {
    cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;
}
```

My question is, do maps store objects in a random order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maps store the content in sorted order.  The reason `"This"` comes before `"a"` is that `'T'` comes before `'a'` in most(if not all character sets) so `'T' < 'a'` and thus `"This"` comes before `"a"` as then length of the string is not considered.

If you change `This` to `this` then you would get

```
a : 4
is : 2
just : 3
test : 5
this : 1
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93138c50d5da4b49)</kbd>